Transaction is not included in a block
I was wondering, why my tx with 10x estimated gas and 10x gas fee is not included in next 10 blocks, and i'm sending this tx directly to Titan and Beaver? Whats the mechanism for builder to pick up my transaction?

Can you share the transaction hash? What network are you using? Is there a pending transaction in the same account? How much gas the transaction uses?

Hello! Now iI'm trying to use bloxroute, at first, everything seems good, bloxroute api returns me hash, but it cant be located even after and hour. Same story with bundles, no matter how many of them I send(to different blocks), not a single is processed. Same story with flashbots and builders. I just cant understand the problem. I'm setting maxPriorityFee to x2, and gasPrice x2 too, i have big gas limit. And when i send same transaction to mempool, it finalyses in 10 seconds... Maybe you can give me an example of your code, which works for your wallet?

Flashbot transaction won't be public until they are part of a block. If a block isn't generated with your transaction that is an issue with bloxroute. You should ask their customer support.

Thank you! I've tried sending private_tx not bundles and 4/5 times i was inlcluded in next couple of blocks. If I understood correctly, to maximize my chances of being included in next block, I should pay bigger priority fees?

You should ask the provider. Transaction ordering is not part of the Ethereum protocol.
